# Stash: Open PR for a feature branch which was previously reverted

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

Others in the Stash community have requested the ability to revert and re-open a merged Pull Request: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-3218

I am facing a similar issue, however I don't care that Stash doesn't provide a way to revert the PR.  The issue that I have is that Stash won't allow me to open a new PR for a feature branch which was previously merged then subsequently reverted.

Scenario:

1. Create branch `feature/US-123` based on `develop` (at commit 0100)
2. Create some commits on the feature branch (commits 0201 and 0202)
3. Merge some other feature branches into `develop` (now at commit 0105)
4. Open PR for `feature/US-123 -> develop`
5. Accept/merge the PR, creating a new merge commit on develop (commit 0106)
6. Decide to revert the merged feature (`git revert -m1 0106`)
7. Either:

   - push the revert directly to develop
   - or preferably, push the revert commit to a new branch (`feature/US-123-revert`) and open/merge a PR to develop
8. Decide to reintroduce `feature/US-123` (perhaps with additional changes)
9. Try to open a new PR for `feature/US-123 -> develop`; note that Stash doesn't show the original commits in the new PR, even though those commits are no longer in the `develop` branch

What's wrong here?
Is it a misunderstanding on my part?
Is this an issue that my scenario introduces?
Or is this actually just an annoying Stash deficiency?

What are some ways to mitigate this?  So far I have:

- Rebase `feature/US-123` on `develop` so the revert commit is included in the feature branch's history.  Prefer not to do this because our current git workflow prohibits us from rebasing feature branches in some scenarios.
- Create a new branch `feature/US-123-rebase` for the previous scenario.
- Revert the revert commit to reintroduce the original merge commit, then add additional commits to the feature branch as needed.
- Others?

Comment: Those older commits exist in your branch, when you reverted the merge commit (if using the UI or creating a revert commit) you just created a new commit which deleted those changes. So you can add those changes back but the original commits should exist.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is Git working as expected. I'm assuming that your original feature branch hasn't moved since the first time you merged it so it's rightfully picking up that there are no commits from that branch that aren't already in the tree for develop.

To get around this, I'd suggest creating a new branch from develop, cherry-picking the commits from the previous branch, then creating a pull request.